# spawn_id is empty when setting

Tags: scripting, expect

I am running an except script where it spawns a c program, waits for an output from the program, and then spawns another program. After that program has finished, I want to send to the original program that was first spawned, but I get the spawned id exp7 not open.

I then tried to get the value of the spawn_id before spawning a new process, but apparently, it is empty, since when I try to do
set old_id $spawn_id
I get the error saying that old_id is not defined.
Do you have any tips on how to spawn a process, then spawn another process, and after that process has finished, to send something to the first process?

Code for the expect script

```
spawn ./practice
set id $spawn_id
expect "Enter:\r"
spawn ./practice2
expect eof
set spawn_id $id
send "he"
expect eof
```

The code in practice and practice2 doesnt make a difference, so I will not post them

Comment: You might want to set an infinite timeout: `set timeout -1`

Comment: Also, if you don't need to interact with `practice2`, then you can simply `exec ./practice2` and not have to deal with the spawn_id